# How to remain fixed positions of layout after dynamically setting the text?

Tags: android

I'm making an application that gets the categories of foods from a remote database and put them in a recyclerView
but the positions keep changing after setting the text,
I need the "see more" to remain on the right side like this

[image].

How can I solve this problem?

This is how it looks now

[image].

That's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTest1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/see_more"
            android:textColor="#26979d"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textTest1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="335dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="9dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:alignment`?

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: I cannot try this myself but I am sure that your `android:layout_width` in the second `LinearLayout` is the suspect. As you can see, the **See More >** is floating in the right however the width itself is restricting it to go further

Comment: An easier way to trace is by looking into the blueprint design of your .xml file

Comment: You got a point! It worked thank you!

Comment: I added it as an answer, please mark it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot try this myself but I am sure that your `android:layout_width` in the second LinearLayout is the suspect. As you can see, the **See More >** is floating in the right however the width itself is restricting it to go further

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CodeRed answer, I found the answer, hope it will help someone else. It was a wrap-content error

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTest1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/see_more"
            android:textColor="#26979d"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textTest1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_right_arrow"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="335dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="9dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```